# Sliver Polygon and its effect on GIS

Tags: slivers

I am new to the subject of GIS and I have been given this topic to prepare for a test. What I understand till now is that sliver polygon occurs when multiple layers are mapped incorrectly. Can someone please explain this in detail to me?
Also, is sliver polygon strictly related to digitization?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For a question like this I think that you should tell us first where you have looked to try and answer your own question before posting it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the definition from Esri:

> **sliver polygon**: [data models] A small, narrow, polygon feature that appears along the borders of polygons following the overlay of two or
>   more geographic datasets. Sliver polygons may indicate topology
>   problems with the source polygon features, or they may be a legitimate
>   result of the overlay.

and from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliver_polygon)

> **Sliver Polygons** is a technical term of the field of Geographic Information System and describes unwanted small polygons resulting
>   from layer intersection.
>
> Sliver Polygons are small areas which result from spatial overlays of
>   different GIS layers. Typically sliver polygons occur if slightly
>   different (often manually) digitalized areas are spatially
>   intersected. Sliver polygons often are characterised by long,
>   elongated areas which do not represent an entity in reality and
>   therefore need to be removed.